# Infinite sum $1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\ldots}}}$ -- does it evaluate to an exact value or approaches a limit

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, continued-fractions

I bumped into the question what does the sum $$1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\ldots}}}$$ evaluate to. It asks whether it evaluates to a value? I'm not sure whether $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the exact value or the limit this sum approaches to in infinity? I think the question implied that it's the exact value, but for me it looks more like a limit, and that the denominator under 1 would never be equal to 1+fraction no matter how many steps the fraction takes.

Comment: see here https://www.theproblemsite.com/reference/mathematics/the-golden-ratio/continued-fraction

Comment: It is a limit.  If it has a value $x$ then we must have $x=1+1/x$.  To see that the limit actually exists, Google "continued fractions".

Comment: "I'm not sure whether $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the exact value or the limit this sum approaches to in infinity" There is **no difference** between the *exact value* and the *limit this sum approaches*.  There is no other possible meaning that could be given to the phrase "exact value".

Comment: The sequence that is formed by truncating the continued fraction at selected points consists of ratios of two consecutive Fibonacci numbers, and does have the Golden ratio as its limit. Any "infinitely long" expression either *is* some kind of a limit or non-sensical. It does not *approach* anything. A sequence of objects may approach some other object, but the totality of this just *is*. Or sits there, if you lprefer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let the number be $x$.  Then $x = 1+\frac{1}{x}$ or

$$x^2=x+1.$$

This has solutions

$$x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}.$$

So if the limit exists, it must be one of those numbers.

Comment: The pattern includes only adding stuff, may it get smaller each time, the quantity will not converge to a negative value ever, therefore the solution $\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is ruled out since $\sqrt{5}>1$. The only solution left is $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Also, think infinite sums, they aren't "limits" but instead the value that the sum evaluates to. Same goes in this case, the quantity you are interested in evaluates to $\varphi$, the golden ratio or $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.